# Provide Local DynamoDB as a service container in Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-devops, amazon-dynamodb, azure-pipelines

I would like to test DynamoDB functionalities using a [service container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/service-containers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) in Azure Pipelines CI. In order to do that the starting point would be converting this docker compose script ([more info here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.DownloadingAndRunning.html)) into Azure YAML:

```yaml
  dynamodb-local:
    command: "-jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -inMemory"
    image: "amazon/dynamodb-local:latest"
    container_name: dynamodb-local
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

I came up with the following [service container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/service-containers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) definition:

```yaml
resources:
  containers:
    - container: dynamodb
      command: "-jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -inMemory"
      image: "amazon/dynamodb-local:latest"
      container_name: dynamodb-local
      ports:
        - "8044:8044"
```

but as far as I can see in Azure the `command` key is [not really supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/jobs-job-container?view=azure-pipelines#container-image)

```yaml
container:
  image: string # Required. Container image tag.
  endpoint: string # ID of the service endpoint connecting to a private container registry.
  env: # Variables to map into the container's environment.
    string: string # Name/value pairs
  mapDockerSocket: boolean # Set this flag to false to force the agent not to setup the /var/run/docker.sock volume on container jobs.
  options: string # Options to pass into container host.
  ports: [ string ] # Ports to expose on the container.
  volumes: [ string ] # Volumes to mount on the container.
  mountReadOnly: # Volumes to mount read-only, the default is all false.
    work: boolean # Mount the work directory as readonly.
    externals: boolean # Mount the externals directory as readonly.
    tools: boolean # Mount the tools directory as readonly.
    tasks: boolean # Mount the tasks directory as readonly.
```

hence I guess that the only way to pass command parameters is given by [additional options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/container-phases?tabs=yaml&view=azure-devops#options):

```yaml
options: "-jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -inMemory"
```

doing so I get the following error:

```
##[error]Exit code 125 returned from process: file name '/usr/bin/docker', 
arguments 'create --name dynamodb_amazondynamodblocallatest_21b96d --label 22b390 
--network vsts_network_35c6003d371042909419226e7fe4016b 
--network-alias dynamodb -p 8044:8044 
-jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -inMemory 
-v "/home/vsts/work/1":"/__w/1" -v "/home/vsts/work/_temp":"/__w/_temp" -v "/home/vsts/work/_tasks":"/__w/_tasks" 
-v "/opt/hostedtoolcache":"/__t" -v "/home/vsts/agents/3.218.0/externals":"/__a/externals":ro 
-v "/home/vsts/work/.taskkey":"/__w/.taskkey" amazon/dynamodb-local:latest'.
```

##### Question

Is there a way to define a Local DynamoDB instance as a [service container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/service-containers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) using Azure Pipelines? **Is it possible to pass *command arguments* to a [service container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/service-containers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) definition?**

### Possible workaround using a Job Task

I found a possible workaround that doesn't involve the usage of a [service container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/service-containers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml). To do so, I created the following `CmdLine` task

```yaml
      - task: CmdLine@2
        displayName: Setup Dynamo
        inputs:
          targetType: inline
          workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
          script: |
            mkdir dynamo-local
            cd dynamo-local
            wget https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/dynamodb-local-frankfurt/dynamodb_local_latest.tar.gz
            tar xfz dynamodb_local_latest.tar.gz
            ls -l
            java -Djava.library.path=./DynamoDBLocal_lib -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -inMemory -port ${{ parameters.dynamoPort }} &
```

Using this approach I can expose to the following tasks an in-memory Local DynamoDB instance accessible via `localhost:parameters.dynamoPort`.